# Python splitlines result changes based on terminal screen size?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have some commands in a file that I'm reading in python and executing using subprocess.Popen. When run splitlines() method, the number of lines that are produced depends on the width of my terminal screen. The commands in the file are:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableforview (name string, dob string) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'location';`

There are no newlines in the file; it is all typed on one line.

```
hivep = subprocess.Popen("beeline -u 'connectionstring' --force=true --outputformat=csv2 --showWarnings=false -f hivetest", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = hivep.communicate()

hivequeryList = []
hivequery = ""

for line in output.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

However, when I print the output of splitlines() method line by line, I get two lines or three lines depending on how large my terminal screen is.

I'm reading the split lines into a dictionary. So what I would expect is for the key of the dictionary to contain the entire create query, and the value to contain the result. But what is happening is the query is getting cut off, like so

`{"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableforview (name string, dob string) STORED AS PARQUE" : "T LOCATION 'location';"}`

And the location at which that cutoff occurs changes depending on how wide my terminal screen is.

I don't know why my terminal screen width should matter when reading from a file. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: There might be some environment variables determining the terminal width, therefore the process that you are opening might be trying to format it's output in accordance to those. Maybe try to use `stdout=` and `stdin=` parameters when using `Popen`?

Comment: Could you post the expected output and what is actually being printed?

Comment: I am using stdout and stdin parameters in Popen. Posted the expected output as well.

Answer (score 1):

The moment you use the `print`, your screen width is used to print your content, if you resize it later, the print has already done its calculations.

Comment: I'm reading the split lines into a dictionary. So what I would expect is for the key of the dictionary to contain the entire create query, and the value to contain the result. But what is happening is the query is getting cut off, like so {"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableforview (name string, dob string) STORED AS PARQUE" : "T LOCATION 'location';"}. And the location at which that cutoff occurs changes depending on how wide my terminal screen is. Please see above edit.

Comment: I don't think that that's how print works. Print is just outputing what you give it into the specified stream (`sys.stdout` by default), the terminal then determines where to split the output lines (ie. where to put a `\n` in it's output). When you resize the terminal, it just calculates it all over again. Print itself doesn't have any idea about terminal width. You can specify any other stream to it, and it would behave exactly in the same way.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik it depends on the terminal, some wont recalculate your text. But the way i said it was like the print was responsible for it, my bad